Transition from Mathematics to TCS
I am an undergraduate majoring in Mathematics and I am really interested in TCS. Most of the classes I have taken are pure math classes so I was wondering: what are the core TCS courses that I should take?

We do not know what classes your university offers but typical TCS courses evolve around Discrete Maths, Combinatorics, Algorithms & Data Structures, Graph Theory, Theory of Computation, Computational Complexity, Crypto, Combinatorial Optimization among others

Throw in some Logic and Category theory. By the way, this question is not suitable for this forum, as it is not research-related. Not meaning any harm, I am voting to close. You might try cs.stackexchange.com

TCS is a vast area, see Wikipedia's list of TCS topics. If you're interested in all of it, I am afraid one lifetime won't be enough. You should be more specific (and saying "I don't know yet" is OK).
